# How to exclude Admin Acounts from People Search Result

Tags: user-profile, search-scope, people-search

I would like to remove all the Admin accounts from People Search results.  I have seen several ways to do it. I didn't want to add a new field in the AD to indicate whether the account is an admin account or not.  I created a SharePoint List that contains all the Admin accounts to be excluded.  I created a metadata that pointed to that list.
I created a new scope to exclude the admin users from the people search result.

Can I do this?

1. Select Scopes.
2. Select People.
3. Select new rule.
4. Select Property Query
5. Select AccountName = AdminAcct
6. Select Exclude

**Question:** Can I Compare a Property query AccountName with another Property query called AdminAcct?

AccountName is populated from User Profile for AccountName.
AdminAcct is new metadata that populates from SharePoint list.

I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: AD is supposed to be the repository for as much user information as is needed to support that user in their daily activities and is the proper place for such a flag to be placed.  By creating your own list of admins, you are now creating a dual maintenance condition where a separate (and likely soon forgotten) list has to be updated any time a new admin account is added.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? Why not put your admin accounts in a separate OU and then set your connection so they do not import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would either define a property within the SharePoint User Profiles that can be used to identify which are admin accounts or use a standard field in AD to designate it.  Once the user profiles are in SharePoint, you can then modify the search scope to add an additional rule that excludes those accounts from People Search.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  I have seen the suggestion where you add a new field to the AD, and reference back to a metadata, and exclude it from the scope.  I'm NOT a server admin. It's hard to get new fields being added to AD.  It would be easy for SharePoint admin to use the SharePoint list concept to exclude the selected users from People search or Employee Directory.

Comment: My recommendation was to add it to the SharePoint user profile, not to AD.  That would still require access to the SP Central Admin and User Profiles to do.  You will not be able to filter people search from a SharePoint list.

Comment: I followed your suggestion to use an existing SharePoint user profile or create a new user profile.  Bring up the profile and edit the value. Crawl the content. I was able to search for it.  Thank you for your suggestion.